# Alloc multiple objects on line line?

Tags: objective-c

`StockHolding` is my own class name, and I want to create 3 instance variables. The working-copy of code is like this:

```
StockHolding *stock0 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
StockHolding *stock1 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
StockHolding *stock2 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

But the first time of my code is like this:

```
StockHolding *stock0, *stock1, *stock2 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

which will not work for me :(

I know that I can create multiple float/int variables in the way :

```
float *x, *y, *z;
```

So my question is, is there any way to make it possible to alloc multiple instance varialbes in such way in Objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StockHolding *stock0, *stock1, *stock2 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

is the same as

```
StockHolding *stock0;
StockHolding *stock1;
StockHolding *stock2 = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

It doesn't really make sense to initialize multiple objects on one line. Your first approach is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What?  Even in C you can't do something like that.

```
int a, b, c = 3; //C is equal to 3, A and B has not been init yet
```

You're only holding an empty address in C.  You can't just apply anything to the pointer unless you allocate memory for it yet, the same applies to Objective-C.

Comment: Yup, you'll have to manually allocate and initialize for every variable.